# Merge dataframes based on only the same column names

Tags: r

How do I merge two (or more) dataframes based on only their shared column names?

For example:

```
df1 consists of ["car", "power", "age"]
df2 consists of ["car", "power", "distance"]
```

When df1 and df2 are being merged, the resulting df should consist of the columns:

```
["car", "power"]
```

I tried to do this via `merge()` but didn't work. `rbind()` and `cbind()` won't work on this and `inner_join` or `outer_join` I also couldn't get to work.

Comment: `won't work, couldn't get it to work, tried merge` doesn't mean much. Please share your code.

Comment: Provide example input and expected output.

Comment: The default behavior is to merge based on common column names. It doesn't make sense that this didn't work. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score -1):

A left join will do what you want.

```
library(dplyr)      
left_join(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't find this one. Is this also possible with more than two dfs or do I have to iterate?